# Securing $HOME and public_html on Ubuntu server 14.04 running Apache2 + userdir

Tags: apache, ubuntu-14.04, user-permissions, selinux, public-html

I am running Apache2 + `userdir` on **Ubuntu Server 14.04**. Users are authenticated against AD and can successfully login to this server via SSH. Each user `$HOME` has `700` permissions to disallow users to change and read other users files.

Directory `/home/public_html` is owned by Apache (`www-data:www-data`) and has permission `775` so each user (members of group `www-data`) can create his own subdirectory in `/home/public_html` under his/her username and create symbolic link to it in his/her `$HOME`. Here is an example for a sample user with username `jdoe43`:

- `/home/Domain/jdoe43` is a $HOME directory (it has permission 700)
- `/home/public_html/jdoe43` is a `public_html` directory of user `jdoe43` which is symbolically linked to `/home/Domain/jdoe43/public_html`

`UserDir` directive is set to `/home/public_html`. The rest of `userdir.conf` is default to Ubuntu installation and is listed below for reference:

```
<IfModule mod_userdir.c>
   UserDir /home/public_html
   UserDir disabled root
   <Directory /home/public_html/*>
      AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit Indexes
      Options MultiViews Indexes SymLinksIfOwnerMatch IncludesNoExec
      <Limit GET POST OPTIONS>
         Require all granted
      </Limit>
      <LimitExcept GET POST OPTIONS>
         Require all denied
      </LimitExcept>
   </Directory>
</IfModule>
```

I'm looking forward to find proper set of permissions **to allow**

- Apache process to access files in `/home/public_html/*`
- Users to have full control over their own `public_html` directories

and at the same time **to disallow**

- a user to see/modify content of another user's $HOME directory
- a user to see/modify content of another user's `public_html` directory located in `/home/public_html/`

All that I tried with different set of permissions ended up either with Apache not to have access to users' `public_html` or with users to have at least read access to other users' `$HOME` or `public_html`.

I found several posts proposing to use **selinux** and configure file system to **deny** access to other users' directories by means of permissions (like I did with `$HOME` by setting it to `700`) and at the same time to **grant** Apache process (by means of `selinux`) to access `/home/public_html` along with all its sub-directories. I also found some resources stating that `selinux` in recent versions of Ubuntu was replaced in favor of `apparmor`, so, as I have limited experience in this  technology, I decided to postpone any movements towards its implementation.

Any suggestions/recommendations are highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Ubuntu or serverexchange is the best place for this question.

Answer (score 0):

There might be a selinux boolean that let you do such thing relatively painlessly.

The ubuntu wiki sends you to the debian SELinux page which confirms that they use the same refpolicies as other distributions (of course). I just checked the policy for apache and the boolean is there.
If you already have a selinux-enabled ubuntu you can easily check whether the boolean is enabled with

```
getsebool httpd_enable_homedirs
```

and check if the boolean true or false (it defaults to false).

As shown [here](http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2010/enable-apache-userdir-with-selinux-on-fedora-centos-red-hat-rhel/), after enabling UserDir you need to enable the boolean

```
setsebool -P httpd_enable_homedirs true
```

And relabel the directories for each user

```
chcon -R -t httpd_sys_content_t /home/testuser/public_html
```

Note that unix permissions on the public_html directory are still 755 or whatever you need for your user/groups setup.

```
chown testuser:testuser /home/testuser/public_html
chmod 755 /home/testuser/public_html
```

If you wish to go the SELinux way that is what you need to do; I don't know much about AppArmor and other alternatives but as you say the Ubuntu wiki is not very clear about selinux support.

If you have some spare time I'd suggest to try it out on a test VM and see how it goes.

Hope this helps!